# Определить SERIAL (AUTO INCREMENT) столбец в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как с помощью запроса в information schema определить serial столбец указав принудительно нужную таблицу.

upd.Решение:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='test' and column_default like 'nextval%'
```

Comment: это? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b062a7cdf89d758c6716e569e166a268

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis да то самое! Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные можно найти в таблице information_schema.columns.
Запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='test' and column_default like 'nextval%'
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b062a7cdf89d758c6716e569e166a268)